# Unable to see processes using ps comand when I configure terminal to auto load my .bashrc

Tags: ps, bash, .profile

My default login shell is bash. From a few online forums, I configured my terminal to auto load my `.bashrc` file whenever I open the terminal by adding:

1. `source ~/.bashrc` in `.bash_profile` OR
2. by adding the following code snippet in `.profile`:

   ```
   if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
       if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
       . "$HOME/.bashrc"
       fi
   fi
   ```

With either of the two, my `.bashrc` loads automatically, but with this I am unable to see the process status using `ps` command.

Note: If I disable the auto loading of my `.bashrc` and manually load it by typing bash, I am still able to see process status using the `ps` command.

Please help me out.

Comment: do you get any errors when you do `ps`?

Comment: whats the content of .bashrc and whats the result of calling `ps`

Answer (score 1):

You can see what `ps` is mapped to by typing `type ps`. Compare before and after the source and you should be able to re-alias it what you're expecting.